# Save changes on a web page

Tags: html, css, google-chrome-devtools, savechanges

I want to be able to save the selections I made on a page. If there's an app or extension that can easily do that, please let me know!

I clicked "Inspect Code" to open Chrome DevTools and tried copying all the code under "Elements" and pasting it in another browser. The page is incomplete, however. No graphics, no data, etc. What else do I need to copy and paste over?

I'm on a site/platform that I can only access with an internal login. Once I am there, I am able to make selections from dropdown menus.

**Every time I have to pull a certain report, I have to select over 200 institutions from a dropdown menu. The next time I go to the site, I want to be able to see those institutions ticked off already.**

Thank you.

Comment: The page likely refers to relative locations to the websites URL, so when you copy it over it loses those connections.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to get all of the code from a website is to do Ctrl + u, which brings you to the website's source code. You could use this to copy the code, but you would have to make seperate files and copy the code in them for `scripts` and `links`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use wget (and a cookies.txt file with your logged-in cookie) to get the page, it's resources, and convert the links to load from your local copies:

```
wget --mirror --convert-links --adjust-extension --page-requisites --no-parent --load-cookies=cookies.txt http://example.org
```

Though I am very curious why you would need to do this...

Answer (score 0):

You could create your own browser extension that checks the boxes for you when the page loads, or you can try to see if [this](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/save-page-we/dhhpefjklgkmgeafimnjhojgjamoafof) browser extension succesfully captures the part of the page you need.

Answer (score -1):

You could try using your browser's developer tools by right clicking some of the data and selecting "Inspect" or "Inspect element". This will most likely take you to a current snapshot of the HTML page you have open. This you should be able to copy paste to a more persistent format.

Comment: Thank you. However, I copy everything that's in the "Elements" tab and paste it in the "Elements" tab of a duplicate page, but it doesn't retain all the data and images. It just shows what I've checked off, but not the results.

Comment: Great, you edited your answer and now someone downvoted me because they think I just repeated what you said :p On StackOverflow it's conventional to append any updates to the bottom of your post with an "Update:", instead of modifying the original, to avoid these confusions.

Comment: Ah, I apologize! I upvoted your answer and tried to explain myself above hah. I am still running into issues with DevTools as I don't know exactly what to transfer over to a new page. Please see above. Thanks!

Comment: You can also have a look on the Networks tab, all the data that's being loaded might be in there, and you could maybe find a network response that contains the filtered data that you're after.

Comment: Another possibility is to develop your own browser extension, these can be triggered on specific page loads, and can automatically check the boxes you want to check with some javascript.